# How to get frame feed of a video in OpenCV?

Tags: c++, opencv

I need to get the frame feed of the video from OpenCV. My code runs well but I need to get the frames it is processing at each ms.

I am using cmake on Linux.

My code:

```
#include "cv.h"
#include "highgui.h"

using namespace cv;

int main(int, char**)
{
    VideoCapture cap(0); // open the default camera

Mat frame;
    namedWindow("feed",1);
    for(;;)
{
    Mat frame;
    cap >> frame;   // get a new frame from camera
    imshow("feed", frame);
    if(waitKey(1) >= 0) break;
}
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Each ms is whatever your framerate is.. e.g. 25 fps is 25 frames you need to store. You could make a vector<Mat> a vector of matrices and push each mat back for 25 then start again, or even a vector<vector<mat>>

Answer (score 4):

I'm assuming you want to store the frames. I would recommend [std::vector](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/) (as [GPPK](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2283946/gppk) [recommends](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18234617/how-to-get-frame-feed-of-a-video-in-opencv#comment26733681_18234617)). `std::vector` allows you to dynamically create an array. The [`push_back(Mat())`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/push_back/) function adds an empty `Mat` object to the end of the vector and the [`back()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/back/) function returns the last element in the array (which allows `cap` to write to it).

The code would look like this:

```
#include "cv.h"
#include "highgui.h"

using namespace cv;

#include <vector>
using namespace std; //Usually not recommended, but you're doing this with cv anyway

int main(int, char**)
{
    VideoCapture cap(0); // open the default camera

    vector<Mat> frame;
    namedWindow("feed",1);
    for(;;)
    {
        frame.push_back(Mat());
        cap >> frame.back();   // get a new frame from camera
        imshow("feed", frame);
        // Usually recommended to wait for 30ms
        if(waitKey(30) >= 0) break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Note that you can fill your RAM very quickly like this. For example, if you're grabbing 640x480 RGB frames every 30ms, you will hit 2GB of RAM in around 70s.

`std::vector` is a very useful container to know, and I would recommend checking out a [tutorial](http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/cpp/cpp_mfc/stl/article.php/c4027/C-Tutorial-A-Beginners-Guide-to-stdvector-Part-1.htm) on it if it is unfamiliar to you.